# Is there a command to get file history of a P4 client spec?

Tags: client, perforce, specifications

Is there a command to get a specific version of a Perforce client spec, or list all versions of a client spec?  It seems to be impossible to do this in the 2009 P4V Windows client. Perhaps it can be done using the p4 command line tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client specs, like other spec objects, can be archived in the Perforce "spec depot".

Unfortunately, the spec depot is not enabled by default, so if you haven't already enabled it, you won't have the older versions of specs.

Here's how to enable and use the spec depot: https://portal.perforce.com/s/article/2445

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks!  I'm relieved to find our spec depot already exists.

Comment: Link’s broken. This is the new link -  https://portal.perforce.com/s/article/2445